# What happens when publishing to Amazon SNS fails?

Tags: java, amazon-sns

I am new to Amazon's services. Now, I use the [AWS SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) with Java. It works fine. I am wondering that when we publish to the SNS, it may fail. If it fails, what will happen? Will the [publish method of the AWS Java SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNS.html#publish-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) retry to publish again or it will not retry to publish?

Comment: There's nothing on the documentation that says that the SDK will retry a `Publish` call, so there's the answer :). You'll get an exception and is up to your application to retry.

Comment: @Augusto , I  also feel the same